# Git reset and checkout by single command

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-reset

Consider I've staged for committing a file (e.g. `db/schema.rb`) that I didn't intended to change. I need to do:

```
git reset db/schema.rb
git checkout db/schema.rb
```

Can I do it by single command?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I tried this one and works well for me:

```
git checkout HEAD -- path
```

Comment: Wow, that really works. I always used shorter `git checkout path`, but it doesn't checkout files that are already staged.

Comment: why `git checkout HEAD -- path` works well, whereas `git checkout -- path` doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1):

I just added this to my `.zshrc` / `.bashrc`

```sh
checkout() {
  git reset "*$1*"
  git checkout "*$1*"
}
```

And then you can just do `checkout <file>` and you're all set.